# Logitech C920 completely useless on Linux, I can't save any settings

Tags: linux, video, webcam, camera

When I tune camera and save those settings, they get reset on boot, on usb connect/disconnect, on select/deselect in Meet settings, when I change browser, when I change camera program, even when I stop video temporarily in the call. On all these events I am supposed to re-run shell script to set exposure settings. Even then one settings that work in Firefox are too dark in Chrome. Also properties are bound so when I restore value for exposure then white balance might get out of tune. In gui apps sliders get stuck, manual modes not always work and sliders still move automatically, also exposure is impossible to tune, i.e. 1280 is too dark, 1281 is too light there is no continuous range.

I find myself adjusting camera settings every 3 minutes during live video calls.

I have tried `v4l-utils, cameractrls, guvcview` to tune it and preserve settings, it's impossible.

Should I get another web camera or switch from Ubuntu to Windows or Android for video calls?

Comment: Did the camera come with proprietary drivers/software for Windows?

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138765/963426). Perhaps also in your case the `uvcvideo` module is not loaded automatically when booting.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using and on what hardware platform?

Comment: This *might* help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/webcam_setup